# Item's unique onclick

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, jsx

I have built a react application which shows items from JSON file, it consists of 4 main components, **Items.js** which created the item itself alongside its props (title and image),  **Itemlist.js** which shows items from  **items.js** and other functions.

**MenuCat** maps and shows each category from the json, and whenever the category is clicked it returns a number(props) to **Itemlist.js**  adding it to the mapping function of items as ( children[{props here}].children[]....) so that it maps all items of each clicked category by using its json index.

Whenever an item is clicked, it shows more JSON properties such as promos inside a pop up called drawer, the content of this pop up is from  **Modifiers.js**.

I need a function similar to **MenuCat.js**'s category clicks but with items instead, where it shows the exact children of the item (e.g Burger 1 shows desert promo 1 on click, and burger 2 shows desert promo 2). The way its set up now, it only shows desert promo 1 for all the items.

Sandbox (current view on app.js): https://codesandbox.io/embed/8j5mmrjk2?fontsize=14&moduleview=1

Comment: Please add your code here, and try asking __one__ question in your question

Comment: "and burger 2 shows desert promo 1" did you mean promo 2?

Comment: @KenoClayton yes, edited.

Comment: @Alpub I'm having difficulty in testing it via codesandbox at the moment (nothing comes on the screen despite multiple reloads. You might want to post the relevant portions of the code in your question for future reference.

Comment: @KenoClayton it is set on sandbox' current module view for App.js

Comment: @KenoClayton sandbox's view option changed on fork, you click the switch and the app will show on App.js and Itemlist.js.

Comment: @Alpub I see it now, thanks, writing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I noticed with your components was that you were passing the `key` attribute. This is anti-pattern as [React does not pass down ref or key props](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html).

> If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop (ex: `<ListItemWrapper key={result.id} id={result.id} />`).

Just pass it down as a different attribute such as `myKey`.

I've done some other tweaks which you can check in the [forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/5k0kj36w6k?fontsize=14). Most notably, I added a state value to track the child index that was clicked.

```
this.state = {
  itemSelected: 0
}

...

{items.children[selected].children[itemSelected].children.map(
  (item, index) => (
    <Modifiers
       key={index}
       title={item.name}
       myKey={index}
       childp={item.children[index].name}
    >
      {" "}
    </Modifiers>
 )
)}
```